# nginx location rules for vue3 ssr

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, location

**ISSUE**

I have a Vue 3 SSR application running in a docker container. I have a second docker container containing NGINX.  I need to have correct location rules in my NGINX container to pass on the correct values to my Vue3 app container.

My application URLs coming into NGINX are

1. `/my/prefix/`
2. `/my/prefix/page1/123?name=one`
3. `/my/prefix/page2/789?id=123&name=one`
4. `/my/prefix/css/styles.css` and `/my/prefix/js/app.js`

I need those URLs to pass onto my Vue app container as the following

1. `/`
2. `/page1/123?name=one`
3. `/page2/789?id=123&name=one`
4. `/my/prefix/css/styles.css` and `/my/prefix/js/app.js`

I can not figure out the correct combination to get this to work.

**What I have tried**

The following resolves (1):  `/my/prefix/` becomes `/`. This on its own however does not resolve (2) (3) and (4), as a result the 2nd and 3rd pages in my app show a 404 and I have no styling and js loaded.

```
location = /my/prefix/ {
    set $upstream http://newserver:8080/;
    proxy_pass $upstream;
}
```

I tried adding the following, with this i have (4) working, styles/js are present, because the the URLs passed on are `/my/prefix/css/styles.css` and `/my/prefix/js/app.js`. *However* (2/3) fail as for the routes in my app for the exact reason the styles/js is working, it passes on the URLS `/my/prefix/page1/123?name=one` and `/my/prefix/page2/789?id=123&name=one` I need it to be `/page1/123?name=one` and `/page2/789?id=123&name=one`

```
location /my/prefix/ {
    set $upstream http://newserver:8080;
    proxy_pass $upstream;
}
```

I tried the following to resolve (2/3). This does match the (2/3) paths only, but what is passed on to the Vue container has the path AFTER page1|page2 removed, i.e. `/page1/?name=one` and `/page2/?id=123&name=one` which is wrong.

```
location ~ ^/my/prefix/(page1|page2) {
    set $upstream http://newserver:8080;
    proxy_pass $upstream/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

I have spent a couple of days trying to get the right combination and I am at a complete loss of what to try next.

Does anyone have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 2 days of trying everything, I have a working solution

```
# URL (1)
# match the root page URL exactly (the = does an exact match the stops searching for rules) 
# - MUST have a trailing / on the location to match our app which appears to always have it
# - MUST have a trailing / on the upstream, so it removes the matched path before passing on
# the path requested and then stops searching for any more matches.
location = /my/prefix/ {
    set $upstream http://newserver:8080/;
    proxy_pass $upstream;
}

# URL (2) (3) 
# match the page1|page2 pages
# remove the path and pass on the paths and parameter values
# $1 references what is in the first ()
# $2 references what is in the second ()
location ~ ^/my/prefix/(page1|page2)(.*) {
    set $upstream http://newserver:8080;
    proxy_pass $upstream/$1$2$is_args$args;
}

# URL (4) 
# match any path starting with /my/prefix/, 
# pass on the url exactly as is (/my/prefix/path/path etc)
# this should match the css/js folders
location /my/prefix/ {
    set $upstream http://newserver:8080;
    proxy_pass $upstream;
}
```